# Retrieving values from multiple tables and displaying in a strongly typed View using List data class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table named Courses,CoursePreRequisites and a third tale named PreRequisiteTracking.One particular Course can contain multiple PreRequisites and so I couldn't pass a foreign key in the Courses tables and instead created the PreRequisiteTracking table.

Eg:A Course,say, Introduction to Java.This may have the following prerequsites:OOPS,Basic Programming Knowledge.
These prerequisites are given in checkboxes while creating a new course. 
Now my problem is how do I join all these tables and list them in a View.
I joined all theses tables but since only Ids are being passed I am not able to retrieve the PreRequisites to show in the View.

Kindly help me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my post.

What I did was in my Class I declared a property as :

```
enter code here
`public class CourseModel{`
`public string coursename{set;get;}`
`public string coursecode{set;get;}`
`public string Benefits{set;get;}`
`public IEnumerable<CoursePreRequisites> display{set;get;}`
       }
```

Here CoursePreRequisites is of table whose value i wish to display in the view.

Then in my controller in the Details action I gave:

```
enter code here:var query=(from cours in db.courses
       join level in db.courselevels on cours.levelid equals level.levelid
       where cours.courseid==id
       select new CourseModel
       {
          coursename=cours.CourseName,
          coursecode=cours.CourseCode,
          Benefits=cours.Benefits,
          display=(from courss in db.course
                   join track in db.prerequisitetrack on courss.CourseId equals                                            track.CourseId
                    join prerequistes in db.courseprerequisite on prerequistes.prerequsiteId equals track.prerequsiteId
                    where track.courseid==id select prerequsite).AsEnumerable()
        }).First() as Models.CourseModel;
```

Then create a strongly-typed view of Class type and give :

```
enter code here:<%foreach(var item in Model.display) {%>  
   <%:item.PreRequisites %>
```

Hope this will be useful to others.I tried and it worked for me.